# ifelse() not storing values properly in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, storage

I'm trying to run this code for a for loop:

```
ifelse(split[[1]]$timeframe == 'post',
       split[[1]]$prcntgwk <- 1,
       split[[1]]$prcntgwk <- 2)
```

It basically is creating a calculation unless the value of column timeframe is 'post', then it will store an NA since the calculation is not applicable

This is my output:

```
> ifelse(split[[1]]$timeframe == 'post',
+        split[[1]]$prcntgwk <- 1,
+        split[[1]]$prcntgwk <- 2)
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
```

But then when I retrieve the column I get this:

```
> split[[1]]$prcntgwk
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Why aren't my values being stored properly??? This makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: Tough to know for sure without seeing the data, but maybe try `split[[1]]$prcntgwk <- ifelse(split[[1]]$timeframe=='post',1,2)`

Comment: *"This makes absolutely no sense at all."* Yes it does. Your call to `ifelse` returns the vector of 2's and one 1 but does **not** assign it to `split[[1]]$prcntgwk` **outside** the function `ifelse`. In R, values assigned inside a function are lost on exit, they only exist in the function, not out of it.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `ifelse`. It returns a value; it doesn't make assignments inside the function itself. It also seems like you're operating on a single index, `[[1]]`, inside every iteration of the loop. But this is a good reason to use vectorized operations, as that's one of R's strengths. Hard to say more without your data or code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the operation element wise and not for the entire vector.

```
> x = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),b=c("post","no","post","post","no","post"))
> x
  a    b
1 1 post
2 2   no
3 1 post
4 1 post
5 2   no
6 1 post

> for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
+ ifelse(x$b[i]=="post",x$a[i]<-1,x$a[i]<-2)}

> x$a
[1] 1 2 1 1 2 1
```

Comment: That's not true; take a look at `?ifelse`. `ifelse` works across the entire vector and returns a vector of the same length. You would want instead `x$a <- ifelse(x$b == "post", 1, 2)`